# Bridge edge loops gives weird results

Tags: edges

I've got two closed edge loops that I want to join using Bridge Edge Loops. One of them is an organic oval-ish shape and one of them is the edge of a cylinder, like so:

[image]

However, when I Bridge Edge Loops, rather than getting the semi-tubular result I expected, I get a weird result with crazy criss-crossed faces, like so:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: added a picture of the edge loops and their normals, for clarity.

[image]

Comment: Uneven topology and unmatched vertex count, most likely

Comment: Unmatched vertex count: probably, I'll check it out. What do you mean by "uneven topology" and why is it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is far from ideal but it's a quick fix:

[image: two loops]

Extrude one of your edge loops and place it near or inside the other one.

[image: s'truuude]

Then bridge them.

[image: bridge]

Select the middle loop, hover over "smooth Vertex" and hold <kbd>RETURN</kbd> until it's stretched.

[image: appeasement]

Of course this creates more horrible geometry. It might be better to use a cylinder made of quads and use a Shrinkwrap Modifier to get an inner wall. Or use the Shrinkwrap to replace the original organic wall with one that has a nice topology.

Blender is not really equipped to handle a lot of chaotic tris. Quads make bridging and other operations much easier and more predictable. Ideally the vertex count of both loops should be the same and the verts should be evenly spaced.

A crazier way:

Hide everything except your edgeloops. if they line up on an axis, hover over the axis in the transform panel (Y in this example) and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

LMB drag the value up until the loops roughly align.

[image]

Bridge them.

[image]

Select the moved loop, hover over the Y axis and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. The loop will be back in its place.

[image]

Yet another way would be to bridge the hole piece by piece and not in one go.

I must admit that so far I haven't been able to recreate your troubles, so the solutions are a bit of guesswork.

Comment: Alas, when I put the two edge loops on roughly the same plane, I still get the same weird criss-crossed edges. I'm going to try to do this in pieces now, see if that works.

Comment: @Bas That's bad. Does it also happen when you do only part of the loop, a quarter maybe?

Comment: It.. depends. I've now resorted to selecting, say, 40 vertices on either loop and doing a bridge edge loop. When it looks sort of okay, I keep them, and move on to the next 40. When they're wonky, I undo and skip those vertices. After I'm done, I look at the holes that are left and either select fewer vertices to do a bridge, or just select three vertices and do a Fill, basically creating polygons by hand. I've had to subdivide some edges to make some of the polygons not so crazy wide and skewed. It wasn't ideal, but I suppose the best I could get with this weird geometry.